# Is there a USB wire that splits into two A plugs for separating data and power?

Tags: usb

I assume it's commonly known around here that USB cables have both wires for communicating data, as well as for sending 5V of power to the device. I commonly tether my computer to my smartphone to get internet through USB, but if I've got heavy usage, the battery in my smartphone slowly dies faster than the low power from my computer can charge it.

I'd like a special USB wire that has a micro plug on one end, but splits to two A plugs on the other. This way I can plug the data portion into my computer, but plug the power portion into the phone's normal AC adapter. I'm assuming the much higher current from the regular charger will keep the phone powered regardless of heavy usage or not.

I was thinking of making this myself, but I thought I couldn't be the first person who wanted something like this. Is there an existing wire that does what I want? Or perhaps an adapter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I safely connect the power-only-end of a USB-Y cable to an other power source?](http://superuser.com/questions/448722/can-i-safely-connect-the-power-only-end-of-a-usb-y-cable-to-an-other-power-sourc), also see [Triple-ended USB cables](http://superuser.com/questions/559589/triple-ended-usb-cables)

Comment: So "Yes" they exist. :) If you're looking for a specific product/shopping recommendation, that would be off-topic.

Comment: Example: http://ca.startech.com/Cables/USB-2.0/Mini/3-ft-USB-Y-Cable-for-External-Hard-Drive-USB-A-to-mini-B~USB2HABMY3

Comment: @techie007 Yes, I believe this is what I was looking for, thank you. It looks like my other option is to use a well powered USB hub. But I think that cable you linked to should be just what i need. Two USB ports worth of power should be plenty. Thanks!

Comment: Well I suppose this http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-3-Feet-Cable-External-Drive/dp/B0047AALS0/ref=pd_sim_sbs_e_2 is what I want, in case anyone else stumbles on this question with the same problem

Comment: @Ramhound No the split wires are the same sizes. They're designed specifically to get extra power for devices

Comment: One other alternative would be a powered hub that has high-current charge ports like many modern laptops, i.e. http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/usb/dub-h7-7-port-usb-2-0-hub

Comment: @cost I thought about it after I made the comment your right

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a solution to meta problem of a USB wire that splits data and power into two separate plugs. The actual problem I was facing was "I have a device that draws more power then the USB port will supply." To this problem, there are two solutions.

First, you can use a Y cable. This is basically a standard USB cable, except there are two Plug Type A plugs on one end. The idea is, you plug these two plugs into two USB ports on the host machine. Since the USB spec only allows a maximum of 500 mA from a port (in heavy usage or on some devices it doesn't even give that - only 100 mA are guaranteed by the spec), this wire is able to get 500 mA from two ports, for a sum of 1000 mA. These wires are small and cheap (under $10), and 1000 mA is enough to power most small electronics. In my case, my smartphone needs 750 mA.

The second solution is to use a powered USB hub that delivers more than 500 mA. Just look in the description of the product, it should point this out. These hubs are a little more expensive than the Y cable, but they give you several USB ports to use, as opposed to you having to give up two. This is also a useful solution if you have a computer or laptop without two USB plugs next to each other.

Comment: IIRC then 5mA is not guaranteed. Only 100 mA is. Up to 500 mA **may** be available after the device asks for it and only if the host grants it.

Comment: @Hennes I'm a software guy, not a hardware guy, but I vaguely recall that you're correct here. My mistake. Now that you mention it, I think some devices are well known for delivering less than 500 mA, like the Wii